# Python: deleting string from first numeric character

Tags: python

How could I delete/split the string below from the first numeric character?

> Good 11 hdle

would become

> Good

the only things I can seem to find are removing numbers OR letters from the whole string

Answer (score 5):

```
import re
str = "some text 12345 other text"
result = re.split("\d+", str)[0]
```